# Xamarin.Android and Spinner binding with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I'm trying to bind to a Spinner using ReactiveUI in a Xamarin.Android application. To add items to the `Spinner`, I need to use `ArrayAdapter`. But `ArrayAdapter` needs `Android.Content.Context`. Should I pass it into the ViewModel?

Anyone know about an application written in Xamarin.Android, which uses ReactiveUI, where I could look inspiration? The ReactiveUI documentation only has a reference to a sample application written for iOS.

#### View

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Label"
        android:text="Zařízení:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Devices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Label"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditCommand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Devices"
        android:text="Edit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### Activity

```
namespace Test.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test.Droid", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : ReactiveActivity, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
    {
        public Spinner Devices { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.WireUpControls();

            // Bindings

            this.Bind(this.ViewModel, ) // ?
        }


        private MainViewModel _viewModel;
        public MainViewModel ViewModel
        { get => _viewModel; set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _viewModel, value); } }

        object IViewFor.ViewModel
        { get => ViewModel; set { ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value; } }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
namespace Test.Droid.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        // How to databind Spinner Devices ?


        public MainViewModel()
        {           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done any Xamarin.Android development, but in general you don't want to pass details about the view into the ViewModel - it should not know anything about the view.

I would expose the list of items as a collection (e.g. `IList<Item>`) and use a converter on the binding to create an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel.Devices, this.View.Property, devices => new ArrayAdapter(devices));
```

`this.View.Property` should refer to the property that changes whenever the list of devices changes. The third parameter (`devices => new ArrayAdapter()`) receives the property from the ViewModel as an argument, you then return a value that can be set on the `this.View.Property`.

> **For example:**
>
> - `ViewModel.Count` is a `string`
> - `View.Property` is an `int`
>
> Bind like this:
>
> ```
> this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel.Count, this.View.Property, count => int.Parse(count));
> ```

The third parameter can be a function or lambda that accepts an argument of the type of the ViewModel property and returns a value of the type of the view property.

Answer (score 0):

I'd said I'd given in providing any feedback on Stackoverflow but anyway... we have a collection of binding extensions, one of which is for a Spinner. in typical usage it looks like this

```
        // bind the options for the distance 
        this.BindSpinner(ViewModel,
            vm => vm.TravelLimitSelected,
            vm => vm.CurrentTravelLimit,
            vm => vm.TravelLimitChoices.Distances,
            f => f.travelLimitSpinner,
            (items) =>
                    new ActionSpinnerAdapter<DistanceChoiceModel>((c, p) => new DistanceLimitViewHost(c, p), items));
```

where in this case, the extension method looks like

```
public static IDisposable BindSpinner<TView, TViewModel, TCommandProp, TSpinnerViewModel>(
             this TView view,
             TViewModel viewModel,
             Expression<Func<TViewModel, TCommandProp>> viewModelCommandName,
             Expression<Func<TViewModel, int>> viewModelSelectedPropertyName,
             Expression<Func<TViewModel, IList<TSpinnerViewModel>>> viewModelSourceItemsName,
             Expression<Func<TView, Spinner>> spinnerControl, Func<IList<TSpinnerViewModel>, ISpinnerAdapter> adapterFactory) where TViewModel : RxViewModel
             where TCommandProp : ICommand
             where TView : class, IViewFor<TViewModel>
             where TSpinnerViewModel : class
        {
```