# What is the proper way to bind ReactiveList to a spinner in Xamarin.Android with ReactiveUI

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.android, android-spinner, reactiveui

I have gone through following reference
[Xamarin.Android and Spinner binding with ReactiveUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135480/xamarin-android-and-spinner-binding-with-reactiveui)
and tried to bind the spinner as follows.

here is my ViewModel Class,

```
public class ExampleVM : ReactiveObject{
    ReactiveList<ExampleTypeResult> _list;
            public ReactiveList<ExampleTypeResult> ExampleList
            {
                get { return _list; }
                private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _list, value); }
            }
    }
```

And Here is My Fragment class,

```
public class ExampleFragment : ExampleBaseFragment<ExampleVM>{
private ReactiveList<ExampleTypeResult> ExampleList;
            Action<ReactiveList<ExampleTypeResult>> action =
                list =>
                {
                    var mItems = ExampleList.Select(n => n._Name).ToList();
                    var adater = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, mItems);
                    adater.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
                    FragmentExampleSpinner.Adapter = adater;
                };

         this.Bind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.ExampleList, v => v.ExampleList, action)
        .DisposeWith(SubscriptionDisposables);
}
```

but this did not worked no errors even. I want to know how can we properly bind reactive list to a Android.Widget.Spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create an `ArrayAdapter` property in your ViewModel. Then use this arrayadapter to bind the spinner.
For example:

```
public class TheViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private ArrayAdapter theadapter;
    public ArrayAdapter Theadapter
    {
        get { return this.theadapter; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.theadapter, value); }
    }
}
```

And set the adapter in activity:

```
        var mItems = new ReactiveList<string>();
        mItems.Add("AAA");
        mItems.Add("BBB");
        mItems.Add("CCC");
        mItems.Add("DDD");
        mItems.Add("EEE");
        mItems.Add("FFF");
        ViewModel.Theadapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, mItems);
        this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Theadapter, v => v.TheSpinner.Adapter);
```

Comment: hi,thanks for the answer. ArrayAdapter contains in Android.widget .how can I put it in my viewmodel class.

Comment: @GayanBuddhika Do you want to set the data to arrayadapter in the viewmodel class? You could create a `Constructor` to do it. You could refer to this link: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/

Comment: Hello, My Point is I can not create ArrayAdapter type property in the viewmodel class because my viewmodels are inside a separate C# Library Project.I cannot use Android things there.Are there any solution

Comment: @GayanBuddhika Have you tried making a class that inherits your `viewmodel`?